# Open Wizard from the Create Method Odoo 13

Tags: odoo, wizard

I want to open a wizard from the purchase.line.order create method in Odoo (v13).

Comment: Improve your question. Do you want to open a wizard from a button? Do you want to open a wizard in create mode? Do you want to open a model as a wizard? It's not very clear if you can add some code.

Comment: I want to open a wizard from the module create method

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what the question is. Good Luck

Comment: opening a wizard (or any UI stuff) from any of the default Odoo buttons (Create, Edit, Discard) will require Javascript work unfortunately.
For any other buttons that can be added to a form it should be easy, but for the Create button to open a wizard is not that simple.
Not even sure why you would want this?